# Does automatic updates reboots Windows Server 2008 - When?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, automatic-updates

Follow up on [previous post](https://serverfault.com/questions/199143/does-automatic-updates-reboots-windows-server-2008).

When does the reboot take place? Can it be controlled?

I think on 2012 there was a task that could be tweaked to control the time.

On 2012 I had the problem that the default task was scheduled on the hour and I have some polling tasks that need to run on the hour. I was able to shift the time but I can't find the task on 2008 R2.

Can I set the 'required reboot' time after Auomtatic Updates determines a reboot is required? To some time other than on the hour?

Comment: This topic should be helpful for you. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mu/2016/10/25/__trashed/

Comment: Interesting command line tool - doesn't help however. The issue is WHEN does the reboot take place and how can I set the time of the reboot.